# Scientifically Correct Alternative Dragon Breath

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, dragons

Besides fire, would it be possible for a dragon to breathe other things like lightning, ice, poison, steam, "life", etc...?

I think it's kind of unlikely for a dragon to release lightning through its mouth to the point of being able to use it as a ranged attack, but I'm pretty new to science, so it might can be possible, i don't know...

The ice i think the dragon could use water as part of the breath that would react with the freezing substance to better incapacitate the target, although it feels more like freezing vomit than breath.

The breath of poison I regard as a gas to which the dragon is immune.

The one for "life" I even put in parentheses because it won't actually be life, it will be more of a pulverized gas or liquid that stimulates the bodies of living beings to be strong and healthy even if the effects are not instantaneous. Like, wounds heal faster than normal, antibodies get stronger so diseases get treated faster, plants grow faster and healthier, etc.

Comment: I hope this question is valid because I tried to make everything a single question and still have a little more originality so that my post is not closed as a copy of another post. ;-;

Comment: Although questions like this have been answered in the past you might have to split it up. "Dragon's breath weapons: how would poison breath work". "Dragon's breath weapons: how would ice breath work". Etc. That makes it easier to go into detail about each individual breath type and get a proper answer. I might have a perfect answer for a poison breath but a bad answer for life breath while someone else might have the reverse. If we have to answer in this question it will both get bloated and hard to judge which answer is best. Add some limitd to magic or people will day "dragon=magic".

Comment: But that way, Demigan, my question is able to be closed as it is considered a duplicate of other posts. After all, how many have asked about ice breathing, poison, lightning, right? And so far I haven't seen much talk about mixing liquid water with something chemical for ice-breath. So far I've only seen it using the moisture in the air for a chemical reaction.

Comment: NArrow down the question by asking what has not been answered in the other posts. MAking a broad question to prevent closure as duplicate doesn't seem a smart choice.

Comment: @WizardKing that is exactly what you need to avoid duplicates. You can already refer to those questions in a link (shows you did research) and then say "I want these basics to be part of my dragon's breath because <reason>, which makes the previous questions different from mine". And the reason can be very simple. Like "hey that using water vapor in the air is nice and all but I want you to point out an animal that can gather enough moisture out of the air to spit. You cant because there's not enough moisture in the air to do that reasonably fast, so moisture of the dragon's body it is".

Comment: Could probably breathe in normal air and then through some esoteric internal processes use the oxygen for energy and breathe out carbon dioxide.... that might work

Comment: I can guaruntee that lightning breath wouldn't work. Lighting is electrons moving from a point of negative charge to a point of positive charge. The target would have to be positively charged, and is also outside of the dragon's body. (Also, there would need to be a medium for electron movement which is better than the dragon's body. All of this requires factors outside of the dragon's body.

Answer (score 2):

**Scientifically correct things would be things that could be plausibly produced with biology.**

There are plenty of struggles on this stack coming up with speculative biology for fire breath.  Ice breath is harder.  "Life breath" is pretty original but pretty fantastic.. unless it is milk?

In any case if you want scientifically plausible "breath" weapons the ones I can think of are as follows:

1. **Caustic stuff.**  Vomit is a common one.  Stomach contents can be acidic.  Bombardier beetles are the extreme with purpose-evolved caustic stuff.  Some ants can shoot acid.  Vinegaroons are the bosses of acid shooting.
2. **Poison.**    Spitting cobra style.  Their venoms have evolved to be contact poisons.  I am not aware of any animal besides cobras that have a ranged poison attack.
3. **Stinking secretions**.  This would be skunk style.  There is no reason it could not be a breath weapon.
4. **Blood.**  Horned toad style.  They shoot blood from their eyes to discourage predators.  It seems like something from an anime.  I guess you work with what you got.
5. **Goo.**   Velvet worms shoot slime and tangle stuff up in it, then eat that stuff. https://thekidshouldseethis.com/post/slime-cannon-attack-how-velvet-worm-slime-jets-work  This is the only ranged attack that is used to collect prey as far as I know.  Lots of other things have defensive goo but nothing else shoots it.  It would be a fine dragon attack.  I wrote a story where a dragon spat blobs of liquid asphalt; it had eaten the stuff cold earlier and kept a reserve warm for its breath weapon.
6. **Irritating hairs.**   These occur in caterpillars and tarantulas.  I have heard of the wind blowing masses of these hairs from caterpillar accumulations and getting them on people, and I think tarantulas can throw them at would-be predators.  It does not seem very dragony - more something some horrible bug thing would do.

Comment: You could add diet. Imagine the dragon eating from the Gimpy tree and storing its hairs to launch at enemies later on. The gimpy tree is also called the suicide tree, so painful are the hairs when they enter your body. Perhaps less extreme, some frogs coat themselves with poison gathered from their food. Your dragon would simply store it in their mouth, which would likely be less hard to evolve than letting it pass the bloodstream towards the skin.

Answer (score 1):

- Volatile or reactive substances such as [chlorine trifluoride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorine_trifluoride). Its body automatically produces it and "wraps it" in copper that it metabolizes to stop it from destabilizing/exploding/all the other bad things, and when the fighting gets serious, it hacks one of these hard-to-produce bio-grenades up and spits it at its enemy; the shell breaks on contact, and they get N-Stoff to the face.
- A [bombardier beetle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bombardier_beetle)-style two-part chemical spray weapon.
- A sphincter at the back of their mouth that shoots keratin (the same stuff hair is made of, so the "ammunition" regrows) darts at their target.

Comment: Holy shit the Germans thought chlorine trifluoride was too dangerous. I wonder how a biological creature would synthesize it and put it into a copper lining before it reacts with the very thing that created it. How to put it into a copper grenade is another question, as is "how is the Dragon going to stay out of the way once it breaks". Even the byproducts can be lethal, if not incendiary/explosive/acidic by themselves.

Comment: Easy. A precursor and the enzymes/catalysts needed to.finalise it, **botn** end up in a copper shell - if calcium carbonate can be deposited as an egg then a copper precursor can be deposited too *handwaves it*.  They mature into pure ClFl3 inside the shell.